# Javascript: Turn a String to an Array with a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have some strings that look like arrays which I'd like to make into real arrays

For example this string...

```
"['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']"
```

...I'd like to become and array of strings:

```
['str1','str2','str3','str4']
```

I think what I'd need to do is run a RegExp on the string to get rid of the brackets ([]), single quotes (') and spaces so its just a string like: "str1,str2,str3,str4" and then simply run the split(',') method but I'm not sure how to make this RegExp

Comment: If you totally trust the source can use `eval()` and it would return the array. Just be aware that eval() can be dangerous. What is source of the string, can it be changed to use double quotes which would let you use JSON.parse()?

Comment: To reiterate what @charlietfl said, using `eval()` can be an _incredibly_ dangerous gamble. You must _absolutely_ **100%** trust where the string comes from.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to use `JSON.parse`. Strings inside JSON string have to be delimited by double quotes, like this.

```
result = JSON.parse('["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"]');
```

This technique will work for `null`, any javascript object or any valid JSON object. You can read about JSON format here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Don't reinvent the wheel! Don't use custom regexes for solved problem.